# Django + Pug(Jade) - how to pass object to mixin?

Tags: django, pug, pyjade

I installed `pypugjs`, added it to `settings.py`, it works fine, but when I'm trying to pass object to Pug mixin - I got a `TemplateSyntaxError` -

`Could not parse the remainder: '{age:20' from '{age:20'`

```html
mixin card(data)
    div #{data}

+card({age:20, name:'Alex'})
```

How to pass more than one named filed to Pug mixin in Django?

Answer (score 0):

you would do it like this:

```
mixin card(age, name)
  div {{ age }}, {{ name }}
+card(20, 'Alex')
```

or alternatively (i simplified to test my answer :)

```
mixin card(data)
  div {{ data.age }}, {{ data.name }}
+card(data)
```

Comment: you need to pass python objects - no json data